# Delegates - Functionality

Tags: iphone, delegates

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Delegates, can't get my head around them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1792815/delegates-cant-get-my-head-around-them)

I am new to iPhone development, just started learning on my own.

While proceding i came up with a word Delegate. Can any one please explain them to me with an example.

Comment: does this answer your question: [iPhone - proper usage of delegates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/338734/iphone-proper-usage-of-application-delegate) ?

Answer (score 1):

Delegates in ObjektiveC are objects with a specific set of methods, which are called by the delegate-using object when something happens. This way, you can avoid subclassing the main object in order to track some state changes.

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Objective-C#Protocols) has something about that