# Objective-c Delegates

Tags: objective-c, delegates

What is the delegates in Objective-c ?

and what is the delegates methods. ?

any one can explain with one example..  please.

tnax and regards.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Delegates, can't get my head around them](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1792815/delegates-cant-get-my-head-around-them) + http://stackoverflow.com/questions/626898/how-do-i-create-delegates-in-objective-c may be

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned [in the Apple developer documentation on Delegations:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Delegation.html)

> Delegation is a simple and powerful
>   pattern in which one object in a
>   program acts on behalf of, or in
>   coordination with, another object. The
>   delegating object keeps a reference to
>   the other object—the delegate—and at
>   the appropriate time sends a message
>   to it. The message informs the
>   delegate of an event that the
>   delegating object is about to handle
>   or has just handled. The delegate may
>   respond to the message by updating the
>   appearance or state of itself or other
>   objects in the application, and in
>   some cases it can return a value that
>   affects how an impending event is
>   handled. The main value of delegation
>   is that it allows you to easily
>   customize the behavior of several
>   objects in one central object.